# Java Multithreading priority: Why in this example, sometimes t1 occurs before t2 is completed, even if t2 has higher priority?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, thread-priority

Example:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{  
public MyThread(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public void run(){
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                +"("+Thread.currentThread().getPriority()+ ")"
                +", loop "+i);
    }
} 
}; 

public class Demo {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
            +"("+Thread.currentThread().getPriority()+ ")");

    Thread t1=new MyThread("t1");    // t1
    Thread t2=new MyThread("t2");    // t2
    t1.setPriority(1);                // t1 priority 1
    t2.setPriority(10);                //t2 priority 10
    t1.start();                        // start t1
    t2.start();                        // start t2
}  
}
```

When I execute the program, some times I have the output like below:

```
//Output1
main(5)
t2(10), loop 0
t2(10), loop 1
t2(10), loop 2
t2(10), loop 3
t2(10), loop 4
t1(1), loop 0
t1(1), loop 1
t1(1), loop 2
t1(1), loop 3
t1(1), loop 4
```

Sometimes I have output like below:

```
//Output2
main(5)
t1(1), loop 0
t1(1), loop 1
t1(1), loop 2
t1(1), loop 3
t1(1), loop 4
t2(10), loop 0
t2(10), loop 1
t2(10), loop 2
t2(10), loop 3
t2(10), loop 4
```

In some other occasions I have output where t1 starts first, and t2 starts before t1 completes all output.

I thought `output1` makes more sense as [“Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority.”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)
How can we understand the reasoning behind this example?

Comment: You might profit from [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned in your post:

> “Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority.”

This does mean, that a thread with higher priority has a higher **likeliness** of being executed than a low-priority-thread. It doesn't mean that a thread with higher priority will always be executed first/finish first. The actual thread-handling depends upon the OS (java simply uses the thread-libraries provided by the OS it runs on).

Comment: for the downvoter: please explain **why** you downvoted the answer

Comment: I did not downvote you, but a possibility is that the answer is quite general and does not address OP's code

Comment: @user140547 yeah, might be possible

Answer (score 3):

Your lower-prioritized thread is started first, therefore it may in some cases complete even before the higher-prioritized even starts. 5 iterations is not that much.
On my (Windows) machine, if I replace the number of iterations with 100, the higher-prioritized thread is consistently selected first.

Answer (score 0):

My notes about threads priorities:

- You can use it for improving performance
- Priorities depends on OS (Windows has 7, Linux ignores them)
- Don't design your app in way where correct working depends on priorities
- If there are some threads with high priorities which are never deactivated, threads with lower priorities can never be run

Comment: If you're collecting rules of thumb, here's another:  Threads that free up resources should run at a higher priority than threads that want to claim them.